# Is there a date function by which i can extract days and then substract them from the current date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function myFunction() {

    var app = SpreadsheetApp
    var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();


    for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {

        var workingcell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1).getDisplayValue();
        var workingcell2 = activeSheet.getRange(i, 7).getDisplayValue();
        if (workingcell == 'TRUE' & workingcell2 == 'Partner Care::Complaint::Payments Issue::Fraud Deduction')

        {

            activeSheet.getRange(i, 2).setValue("Incorrect Data");

        }
    }

    for (var j = 2; j < 10; j++) {
        var workingcell3 = activeSheet.getRange(j, 1).getValue();
        var todayDate = new Date();

        if (todayDate.getDay() - workingcell3.getDay() > 30) {
            activeSheet.getRange(j, 8).setValue(">30 Days");


        }
    }

}
```

This code is compiled but it does not serve the objectives which are as follows:

1. To check if the range of cells in A contain the word "TRUE". If yes then mark -- "Incorrect Data"
2. To check if the range of cells in column number 5 (E) have a date that is greater than 30 days old

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your code work as expected, I suggest you make the following changes to it:

#### Snippet

```
for (var j = 2; j < 10; j++) {
   var workingcell3 = activeSheet.getRange(j, 5).getValue();
   var sheetDate = new Date(workingcell3);
   var pastDate = new Date();
   const pastTime = pastDate.getTime() - 30 * (24 * 3600 * 1000);
   if (pastTime > sheetDate.getTime()) {
      activeSheet.getRange(j, 8).setValue(">30 Days");
   }
}
```

The above snippet parses the `workingcell3` cell's value as a date and it also creates a constant `const pastTime` which represents the date from 30 days ago. For calculating the day from 30 days ago, the following formula has been used:

```
past_date = today_date - number_of_days * (24 * 3600 * 1000)
```

Afterwards the two dates are compared by using the `getTime` method and based on that, the cells are updated with the `">30 Days"` value.

#### Reference

- [JDBC Service Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc)

Comment: Thank you so much @ale13, it really helped me. However, the first part of my code seems to have a problem because "Incorrect Data" is only getting printed on one cell and that is (1,2). I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: Make sure the ranges for `workingcell` and `workingcell3` are different. In the code you have provided, they're both the same - which may cause the issue. The first part is working with no issues for me, so I suspect the above might be the cause for it.

Comment: Thank you very much! One final question. I want to understand how to run the code for only a range till which the cells have data. I have defined a variable using the last row function. But i am not sure how i should use the var.

  var lastrow = activeSheet.getLastRow();

Comment: If you want to get all data excluding blank lines, consider doing  [`sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) instead of `getRange(j,5)`.

Otherwise, you could also just add a check (`if`) to skip blank cells.